# Determining a which checkbox is checked on a datagrid and updating DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a TemplateField and checkbox in this field. I will marking these check boxes as either checked or not depending on a 1 or 0 in the database.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Normal User Logging">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="normalLogging" Checked='<%# Eval("normal_toggle") == 1 %>'
            AutoPostBack="true" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I will have multiple rows in this datagrid. I am wondering how I will determine which checkbox is checked whenever one is checked. Such as, how do I know a person clicked on the third row checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you stated, it's not the Checkboxes which will perform the PostBack, but some other button, So you can check your whole selection at once. In that case, Checkboxes should not be `AutoPostBack="true"`.

That said, your Button's code would be something like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
    CheckBox cb = row.FindControl("cb") as CheckBox;
    if (cb != null)
    {
        if(cb.Checked)
        {
            //Do your thing here
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

OP (Justin) posted that he wants to update DB for each CheckBox click. In that case, the solution is handle the CheckBox's `OnCheckedChanged` event:

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Normal User Logging">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="normalLogging" 
                      Checked='<%# Eval("normal_toggle") == 1 %>'
                      AutoPostBack="true" 
                      OnCheckedChanged="cb_CheckedChanged" 
                      yourID='<%#Eval("yourIdField") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
protected void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Checkbox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    string yourID = cb.Attributes["yourID"];
    //Do your thing
}
```

Comment: No, I am posting back whenever a checkbox is checked. I want it to update the DB and reflect that to the user.

Comment: Ok, that looks good. However my question still remains on how to determine which box was checked. So in the code behind, how do I know it was the 4th row's checkbox and not the 2nd? I just see the checkbox object being sent, but I don't see a way to determine which row it was in.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are right. I updated my answer to include that. Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh, and let me know how that turned out.

Comment: I am working on this right now and from what I am seeing in the output, I am getting this in the rendered markup:
<span myID="4">
...checkbox input here...
</span>

So my concern is that when my checkbox posts back, it won't have this custom attribute I have set. The browser wouldn't even know to post that back anyway as it only knows to post back if the checkbox is marked or not.

Answer (score 1):

you create your column with a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn control type, and use the Click events and CellContentClick, see example below

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        col.Name = "ColumnName";
        col.HeaderText = "HeaderTest";
        col.TrueValue = "True";
        col.FalseValue = "False";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
        this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ColumnName")
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue) 
               //your code here            
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ColumnName")
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue) 
             {
                //your code here
             }
        }
    }
```

Regards